# Joining on variables with two different formats

Tags: sql

I have a problem where I have a year of birth attribute in table X (format: yyyy)  as well as a date of birth attribute in table Y (different format: dd-mm-yyyy).

They are both varchar() type attributes. I want to join these tables on these attributes. For example, I want to select the names of all the people born in the same year. How can I do this?

Comment: In what table are the names of the people? It seems to me you don't need the two tables to do that.

Comment: Which RDBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer, etc) are you using? String and date functions/operators vary between RDBMS.

Comment: @Mark I am using SQLite.

Comment: @Jerry It is just an example, the problem lies in matching those strings in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Should that be WHERE X.YearofBirth = RIGHT(Y.DateOfBirth,4)? I am not nitpicking -- I haven't seen this construct.

Comment: Yes, I first put the tables and looked if you had the column names and forgot to update the X table. Let me try again: `WHERE X.YearOfBirth = RIGHT(Y.DateOfBirth,4)`.

Comment: @Jerry: SQLite doesn't have a RIGHT function, although I have suggested something similar using SUBSTR and LENGTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Updated) Assuming the date-of-birth attribute consistently has the last four characters as the year, try:

```
select...
from X
join Y on X.year_of_birth = substr(Y.date_of_birth, length(Y.date_of_birth)-3,4)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4fc63/2).

Comment: There is another problem then, day 01 is truncated to day 1. The months behave this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
JOIN table2 ON DATE_FORMAT(table1.bday, "%Y") = DATE_FORMAT(table2.bday, "%Y")
```

Comment: DATE_FORMAT isn't a SQLite function.